# Applying a built-in JS operator

Tags: javascript

Say I want to add a sequence of numbers using `reduce`:

```
[1,2,3].reduce((all, current) => all + current, 0)
```

is there any *built-in* (I know I can write an auxiliary function that does this) way to pass the `+` operator as an applicable function? E.g.:

```
[1,2,3].reduce(+, 0)
```

I know the above isn't valid JS, but I hope it demonstrates what I want to achieve.

Comment: You may want to write different operand functions and pass those functions instead.

Comment: You might want to look at libraries like [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/), they allow you to write more functional code. For example you already have what you need in the [reduce implementation](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#reduce).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, no such symbol exists. But you can just write it yourself as you pointed out:

```
const Operator = { plus: (a, b) => a+b };
//...reduce(Operator.plus, 0)
```

The answer to your question is simply: no.

Answer (score 1):

**There is no built in function like that.**

This is totally a hack and will probably replace the native `reduce` functionality.

```js
Array.prototype.reduce = function (operator, inital) {
  // Assuming operator is always = "+" 
  // You need to implement your versions for subtraction, multiplication etc may be using a switch case
  var sum = inital;
  this.forEach(elem => { sum += elem });
  return sum;
}

console.log([1, 2, 3, 4].reduce("+", 0))
// 10
console.log([1, 2, 3, 4].reduce("+", 10))
// 20
```

Comment: I don't think it answers the question at all, modifying the prototype and using strings and switch cases is definitely not built in.

Comment: Well then, NO!! is the answer for this question? Please share if you have a correct answer. I would be happy to delete this.

Comment: Probably, javascript is not python

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for a built-in way to do this, without modifying `prototype` or writing extra functions. Sorry if this wan't clear.

Answer (score 1):

```
const op = k => {
  "+": (a,b) => a + b,
  "-": (a,b) => a - b,
  "/": (a,b) => a / b,
  "*": (a,b) => a * b
}[k];
```

So you can do:

```
[1,2,3].reduce(op("+"))
```

(The startvalue is not neccessary here)

Reduce could be wrapped in another function to shortify this even more:

```
const reduce = (arr, o,s) => arr.reduce(typeof o === " function" ? o : op(o), s);
```

So you can do:

```
reduce([1,2,3,4],"+");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for people who use Lodash.

You can use the available `_.multiply`, `_.add`, `_.subtract` and `_.divide` functions with `Array.reduce`.

Here is an example:

```
function calculate(operand, elements) {
    return _.first(elements.reduce((acc, cur) => _.chunk(acc.concat(cur), 2).map(c => _[operand].apply(null, c)), []));
}

// Then

calculate('add', [1,2,3,4,5]);   // 15
```